# What is the difference between loading a Google API via callback or google.load or simple script block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I think google API's can be loaded in your page by three different ways:

1: Uisng a simple script block. like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/googleapis.com/maps/file.js"></script>
```

2: Using a callback where you do something like

```
var sc = document.createElement("script");
     sc.type="text/javascript";
     sc.src = "http:/googleapis.com/maps/file.js&callback=func_Name";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

3: And then using someting like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
              google.load("maps", "1");
```

**My question: Is there any significant difference between the three approaches or it just doesn't matter. Can I use the search and maps API in a project, where I call use search API using google.load and maps just as a script block?**

Comment: Yes, the difference is speed: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: @Bondye, the question is about different methods of loading Google's own APIs, not external libraries like jQuery hosted by Google vs self-hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The first script block will block until the browser has loaded the script file and then execute it. You will be able to use maps directly after the script block. Its the synchronous loading option.

The next 2 option are asynchronous.

The second option instructs google maps to initialize and then call a method specified with the callback parameter. With this approach you decide, when is the best time to load the maps api. So either on demand or after the page has loaded.

The 3rd approach loads the maps api via the google javascript loader. It gives you actually the same benefits as the second option, just that you dont have to write the insert of the script tag manually. The docs about the google loader also says, that your page should already have been loaded when you call it (https://developers.google.com/loader/). However in this case you load an additional file, but you can also use it to load other libraries like e.g. jquery. the google loader also offers to specify a callback parameter in the third object argument, that will be called, when the script is available.